# how to create ufs filesystem more than 2tb in solaris?

Tags: solaris, ufs

how to create ufs filesystem more than 2tb in solaris?

Comment: Which version of solaris ?

Comment: i want in both 9 and 10..

Comment: you souhld be able to do that with newfs and mkfs commands? are you getting errors? if so, what are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do this on 64bit Solaris systems. The Solaris 10 [**newfs manpage**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5166/newfs-1m.html) has the example below for creating a multi-terabyte UFS filesystem. It looks like the same should work on Solaris 9 8/03 or later. You should look [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-5093/fsoverview-12343.html#fsoverview-18) for information on support and limitations of mutli-terabyte UFS filesystems. There is an example [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-5093/fscreate-6.html#fsoverview-14) on the Oracle site that suggests that suggests they can be created directly.

```
 # newfs -T /dev/md/rdsk/d99
 newfs: construct a new file system /dev/md/rdsk/d99: (y/n)? y
    /dev/md/rdsk/d99: 1677754368 sectors in 45512 cylinders of
    144 tracks, 256 sectors
    819216.0MB in 1821 cyl groups (25 c/g, 450.00MB/g, 448 i/g) ...

 Then, if you increase the volume size for this file  system,
 you  can  use  the growfs command to expand the file system.
 The file system is grown to 1.2 terabytes in this example:

 # growfs -v /dev/md/rdsk/d99
 /usr/lib/fs/ufs/mkfs -G /dev/md/rdsk/d99 2516631552 /dev/md/rdsk/d99:
    2516631552 sectors in 68268 cylinders of 144 tracks, 256  sectors
    1228824.0MB in 2731 cyl groups (25 c/g, 450.00MB/g, 448 i/g)...
```

Answer (score 3):

To address a partition that is bigger than 2TB, you'll have to use EFI disk labels (instead of SMI). Remember Solaris doesn't boot from EFI disks yet, so your boot disk must use SMI and it can't be bigger than 2TB for that reason. Additional disks attached to your server can use EFI just fine.

Solaris 10 (newfs, ufsdump, etc) has been updated to handle >2TB file systems. Solaris 9 since update 8/03 also has support.